# BCryptHelper.CheckPassword always returns false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bcrypt, string-hashing

I'm implementing password hashing using BCrypt, which should be pretty straight forward to use.
However when the password is checked against the hashed password using

```
BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(Password, hashedDBPassword)
```

this always return false.

Here is my hasher class:

```
public static class BCryptHasher
    {
        public static string EncryptPassword(string password)
        {
            var passwordToHash = password;
            var hashedPassword = BCryptHelper.HashPassword(passwordToHash, BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt(6));

            return hashedPassword;
        }

        public static bool CheckPasswordMatch(string userPassword, string hashedDBPassword)
        {
            return BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(userPassword, hashedDBPassword);
        }
    }
```

I have debugged to check if the password and hashedPassword are correct.
Not many other cases of this problem exist so there must be something I am doing wrong.

I found the same question here: [ASP.NET MVC 3 app, BCrypt.CheckPassword failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222268/asp-net-mvc-3-app-bcrypt-checkpassword-failing) but no solution has been found yet.

Maybe there are other and better solutions for hashing?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is not in the hashing itselft, maybe it's the way you store the password in the database and retrieve it afterwords or something like that.

First step I would take is to write a unit test to check the functionality of that class

```
[TestClass]
public class BCryptHasherTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void check_hashing_works_for_valid_password()
    {
        string password = "myDummyPassword!";
        string hashedPassword = BCryptHasher.EncryptPassword(password);

        var passwordsMatch = BCryptHasher.CheckPasswordMatch(password, hashedPassword);      
        Assert.IsTrue(passwordsMatch);
    }
}
```

If this passes, the problem is somewhere else in your code, so you can go ahead and test for other things until you have found the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was that I stored the hash as a nchar() for some reason. Changed this to char() and it works!
What I don't get is why. The nchar() is supposed to accept more characters than a char() if i understand correctly..